# Python How to find index of second Uppercase letter in a string

Tags: regex, python-2.7

I want to get the index of the second uppercase letter in any string.

For example, in the string "Paul likes Ice cream" I want to get the index of the "I", which is 11. It should work for any string though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
m = re.search(r'^([^A-Z]*[A-Z]){2}', 'Paul likes Ice cream.');
print m.span()[1]
12
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like

```
>>> string = " Paul likes Ice cream." 
>>> [ match.start() for match in re.finditer ("[A-Z]", string) ][1]
12
```